# Transistion between images in the frame animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

i am using ***frame animation*** to display set of images one after the other and it works fine , ***except that the transition between the images is not good*** .I **need smooth transition** like ,the first image ***fades out*** and the next image **fades in**.How to achieve such transition in the ***frame animation***.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you may increase a number of frames in your animation by adding faded images to simulate smooth transition.